# MySQL Connection timeout on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout

I just check other posts on stack overflow about the connection timeout, but looks like everybody fixed it using

```
com.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
```

and

```
dbaccess.ServerAddress = "Server=mysql;Database=MyDB;Connect Timeout=2147483;Uid=username;Pwd=mypassword";
```

Unfortunately, I still get this error message after 40 seconds:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

You can take a look at the two screenshots.

MySQL Workbench works fine and it takes 48 seconds in executing the same query.

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tplLr.png)

[Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHzFs.png)

I can not use limits to reduce the subset acquired because I am centralizing information split in different tables. A stored procedure can not be use since the information is stored in different mysql servers too.

Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Fernando

EDIT:

This is the code. I posted the image to show the execution time, not the error message.

```
public DataSet ExecuteQuery(string[] Query,  TableMap[] TableMappings)
{
    //Mysql vars
    MySqlConnection con;
    MySqlCommand com;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds;

    con = new MySqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = _serveraddress;

    con.Open();

    com = con.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    foreach (string st in Query)
    {
        com.CommandText = com.CommandText + st;
    }

    com.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;

    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);

    foreach (TableMap tm in TableMappings)
    {
        adapter.TableMappings.Add(tm.SourceTable, tm.TableSet);
    }

    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code starting at instantiating what ever is behind `dbaccess` till opening the connection.

Comment: what happens if you change `int.MaxValue` to 5000?

Comment: @SimonPrice same error :(

Comment: @Seteve Sorry for the picture. I was trying not to show the error message but the execution time.

Comment: This cant be your code. `dbaccess` does not exist in your edit.

Comment: This method will practically force you to write code that is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You need an additional mechanism to accept query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem lies in this line

```
 adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);
```

Here you pass the command text to the new MySqlDataAdapter. Of course this MySqlDataAdapter has no knowledge of the timeout you have set on the command because the twos (adapter and command) are no linked together.

If you change to

```
 adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
```

Then your adapter will use the MySqlCommand and its CommandTimeout property

Said that, I really recommend you to start approaching database code following the well established patterns

```
public DataSet ExecuteQuery(string[] Query,  TableMap[] TableMappings)
{
    // using statement will ensure proper closing and DISPOSING of the objects
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_serveraddress))
    using(MySqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        // Not needed, it is the default
        // com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        foreach (string st in Query)
        {
            // Are you sure the st is properly terminated with a semicolon?
            com.CommandText = com.CommandText + st;
        }
        com.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        using(MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com))
        {
            foreach (TableMap tm in TableMappings)
               adapter.TableMappings.Add(tm.SourceTable, tm.TableSet);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
       }
    }
}
```

The using statement is really important here, in particular with MySql that is very sensible to connections not closed correctly and could stop your program with error messages about *no more connections available*.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Pwd` to `password`. Also the property `server` should be set to an ip or domain.

```
conn = "Server=[ip/domain];...password=mypassword";
```

Wrong credentials would result in a failed login, not a timeout. I guess it really tries to connect to `mysql`. If the server is running on your local computer just set `localhost` as server.

Comment: @Steve Thank you. It works! I took your advice on the "using" command. I would modify the rest of mysql call to use the "using". Again, thank you

Comment: In the `server` parameter i am using the computer name since this is use on the itnernal network or the VPN. Should i use the FQDN of the internal domain name? What is your recomendation in here? I am open to improvements

Comment: That strongly depends on your software. On local network I guess there are no big benefits for one of them. I generally provide settings to change the db-connection form user-side so this question would fall off. The only thing I can say for sure is to rather use a representation of the ip like a FQDN or computer-name (never tried that) to keep on the connection even if the ip changes.